# Execute SSH Script via Command Line and then Close Shell

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, putty

I am trying to schedule a mysqldump through SSIS and the only way I see possible is through the command line with Putty. My command looks something like this:

```
    putty.exe user@host -pw password -m script.txt
```

Inside my script is my mysqldump command:

```
    mysqldump -h host -u username -ppassword schema > dump_file.sql
```

When I test this with a dummy database, it works because the time it takes to complete is less than a minute, so it would run the command, open up a shell, execute the script, and exit the shell after it is done.

My issue now is with a live database, it takes longer and my connection eventually times out and the connection is lost and the shell never closes (even though the dump is successful). So this causes my SQL Server Agent job to be hanging and never ends.

Is there a way that I can run the script and then exit the shell without waiting for it to finish first?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the mysqldump command in background by using &.

```
      nohup mysqldump -h host -u username -ppassword schema > dump_file.sql &
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but does that close the shell connection at the end of it?

Comment: I tried adding this to the end of it. My SQL Agent job completed in 6 seconds, but backup was not actually backed up. My backup file size is 0MB.

Comment: This might be helpful https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/

Comment: nohup command may come to your rescue https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: The issue I am having is that the script is the actual shell, so the shell exits automatically when the script is finished executing. Even after adding the nohup and & to my script, the shell does not close until the process is completed. I need a way to execute the command and then close the shell. This is all done through SQL Server Agent so no one is in front of the computer to input commands.